# Open window behind another application

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke

I want to open few windows (IE window, Outlook mail windows, notepad windows) by a click of a button on my application.

Problem: When I click on the button and all these applications open one after the other. My own application (on which the user clicked) is lost in the window clutter.

I want to open all these windows behind my application. Any suggestions ? Any standard API's which I can use to achieve this kind of behavior ?

Logic: I want to do something like open window with window placement = 2 in the Z order of windows. This way, my window, which is active will always be at the top (z order = 1) when other windows are opening.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks

Karephul

UPDATE:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
I used this PInvoke to set my application window as topmost. then all the other windows will automatically open behind it. Once done, I un-set the topmost window flag using the same PInvoke. More details in the link I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the TopMost property of your form to True.

Make sure you allow users to change that or only do it for a short period, because it does get annoying to users.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways, call the win32 command SetForgroundWindow or toggle topmost.

---

To toggle topmost do the following. This will bring the window to the front but not leave it as topmost which is pretty annoying.

```
// Launch applications (Process.Start(...))
TopMost = true;
TopMost = false;
```

---

To call the Win32 Command

> [DllImport("user32.dll")]
>           [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
>           static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
>
> ```
> ...
>
> // Launch applications (Process.Start(...))
> SetForegroundWindow(this.Handle);
>
> ...
> ```

Comment: I end up using "SetWindowPos" P/Invoke call. SetForeGroundWindow is what I was using but it has that flashy effect. New window will start .. it will come in-front and then we SetForeGround to your app which will then come on top.. if it happens for 10 widows .. imagine the clutter.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more intrusive than you like but I discovered by accident while doing some Office interop that after opening the office apps and files that you can issue

```
MessageBox.Show("All files have been opened.")
```

And this should bring your app (and the messagebox)frontmost.

Comment: This will flash all the windows on the desktop. Which is kind a annoying.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) Classes [Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) method you can set Application variables for the process state when launched using the [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx) class and passing it into the overridden method [Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) as a parameter. There is a property ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle which is of type [ProcessWindowStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle.aspx) which has 4 values Normal, Hidden, Minimized and Maximized, by setting the value to Minimized you can regain focus and be easily brought to the front.

Code from MSDN

```
    // Uses the ProcessStartInfo class to start new processes,
    // both in a minimized mode.
    void OpenWithStartInfo()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

        Process.Start(startInfo);

        startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com";

        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
```

Comment: We've looked into this option but that means is user has to restore all the windows to see whats in there. So, we decided against it.